# Как исправить ошибку?

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Было

```
//Соединение с БД MySQL
 $db_connect = mysql_connect( BEZ_DBSERVER, BEZ_DBUSER, BEZ_DBPASSWORD ) or die(BEZ_ERROR_CONNECT);

 define('BEZ_CONNECT', $db_connect);

 mysql_select_db( BEZ_DATABASE, BEZ_CONNECT )or die(BEZ_NO_DB_SELECT);

 //Устанавливаем кодировку UTF8
 mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
 mysql_query ("set character_set_client='utf8'");
 mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
 mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
```

Сделал

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname={BEZ_DATABASE};host={BEZ_DBSERVER}", BEZ_DBUSER, BEZ_DBPASSWORD);
$dbh-> exec("
    SET NAMES utf8;
    set character_set_client='utf8';
    set character_set_results='utf8';
    set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'
");
```

> Warning: PDO::__construct()
> [pdo.--construct]:
> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
> failed: ���� ���� ����������. in
> Z:\home\localhost\www\php\bd\bd.php on
> line 15
>
> Warning: PDO::__construct()
> [pdo.--construct]: [2002]
> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
> failed: ���� ���� ����������. (trying
> to connect via
> tcp://{BEZ_DBSERVER}:3306) in
> Z:\home\localhost\www\php\bd\bd.php on
> line 15
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'PDOException' with message
> 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
> failed: ���� ���� ����������. ' in
> Z:\home\localhost\www\php\bd\bd.php:15
> Stack trace: #0
> Z:\home\localhost\www\php\bd\bd.php(15):
> PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname={B...',
> 'root', '') #1
> Z:\home\localhost\www\php\index.php(33):
> include('Z:\home\localho...') #2
> {main} thrown in
> Z:\home\localhost\www\php\bd\bd.php on
> line 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой строке:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname={BEZ_DATABASE};host={BEZ_DBSERVER}", BEZ_DBUSER, BEZ_DBPASSWORD);
```

у вас не распарсивается значение предопределенных констант. Так можно только с переменными делать.

Правильно так:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".BEZ_DATABASE.";host=".BEZ_DBSERVER, BEZ_DBUSER, BEZ_DBPASSWORD);
```

Comment: @VenZell, после константы "BEZ_DBSERVER" кавычка лишняя.

Comment: @VenZell и @Deonis, спасибо.

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо, исправил.